# How to shutdown my PC when such a thing happens plz help?

Tags: 16.04, kernel, shutdown, windows-10

It happened almost 3 times when i installed Ubuntu 16.04 alongside windows (or even as main OS) for me or  for one of my friends ,that after installation is done  and I should restart  the PC ,it won't shut down and stayed  stuck refusing to shut down even with pressing the laptop power button  .In the 1st time there was a notification on the black screen’’kernel offset:disable ‘’. I spent 2.5 hours till  i found a solution on youtube to turn it off through plugging out the power cable and removing the batteries then starting again(I am not sure if this action would not harm my PC hardware in the long run ??is it ?).In the last 2 times there was not any notification regarding the Kernel offset as before ,in these 2 times i succeeded to turn the Pc off  from the power button directly.Why such a thing happens.. What action should man take in such cases..How to avoid such a thing from happening again!!!!Thanx in advance

Comment: When nothing else works, press the power button **and keep it pressed** until it shuts down (it always does).

Comment: Thanx @CelticWarrior ...in the first aforementioned time  i really    did that and kept pressing the power button for about  25  sec but i finally gave up ,i was afraid something wrong happens if i kept pressing longer.